# What is the difference between Consumer and Client SSD?

Tags: ssd

Does anyone know what are the differences between Consumer and Client SSD :
https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-970-pro-nvme-m2-1tb-mz-v7p1t0bw/ versus
https://www.samsung.com/us/business/products/computing/ssd/client/970-pro-1tb-mz-v7p1t0e/

https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-860-pro-2-5--sata-iii-2tb-mz-76p2t0bw/ versus https://www.samsung.com/us/business/products/computing/ssd/client/860-pro-2tb-mz-76p2t0e/

Answer (score 1):

Your two exampels earch are identical - one is a product presentation, the second link a shop, but the products on each pairs are EXACTLY THE SAME. Some marketing guy came up with different terms on different websites, that is all. Once you look into the specs both are Client PC usage and both are basically the same product (obviously 2 products, but I go with your pairs here).